# Python Decoding with Errors=Replace

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8, python-unicode

Using Python 2.7, I'm grabbing some HTML from a website as strings and immediately decoding it into unicode. Because I need to know later where any decoding errors occurred, I thought it would be best to use errors="replace" to prevent exceptions from non-ASCII characters:

```
linkname = curlinkname.decode("utf-8", errors="replace")
```

In most cases, this replaces the problem character with a placeholder. However, when I run the code I am still getting an exception from this line on one particular character (ū):

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u016b' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>
```

What's going on?

Comment: Maybe the encoding is not utf-8, check it first you can use this lib for the encoding detection https://github.com/chardet/chardet

Comment: Can you please share the full traceback?

Comment: are you reading from text file?

Answer (score 1):

you need to install the lib first

```
pip install chardet
```

then use it

```
import chardet
code = chardet.detect(curlinkname)
linkname = curlinkname.decode(code['encoding'], errors="replace")
```